# CKEditor - Using GetData()

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I am struggling with implementing the following:

I have the a button which creates the CKE instance (outside the form):

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" onclick="javascript: var editor81 = CKEDITOR.replace('divtext81')" value="Edit">Edit</button>
```

I then have a save button (outside the form):

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" id="save81" value="Save">Save</button>
```

I then use the following javascript to post to a mySQL database:

```
        $(document).ready(function (argument) {

        $('.btn').click(function () {



            id = $(this).attr('id').replace('save','');

            $edit = CKEDITOR.instances.editor81.getData();

            $cid = $('#cid' + id).val();

            $action = $('#action' + id).val();

            $eid = $('#eid' + id).val();

            $.ajax({

                url: 'include/editupdate.php',
                type: 'post',
                data: {
                    data: $edit,
                    cid: $cid,
                    eid: $eid,
                    action: $action
                },
                datatype: 'html',
                success: function (rsp) {
                    alert(rsp);
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

The information posts fine to the database except it does not pick up any data from the editor instance, so that field is always blank. All of the other fields are OK. The suffix 81 is the record ID.

I also would like to know how to close the editor instance after posting to the database.

Many thanks

Comment: By close you mean hide it?

Comment: I think the call is editor.destroy(),

Comment: yes (http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editor-event-change) or you can hide it with `.hide()`